# Dynamic levels brick breaker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a brick breaker game with dynamically loading levels. I'd like to stay in one scene the entire game, and then dynamically load different levels by changing the brick positions (e.g. one level in where the bricks are in the shape of a circle, another level where the bricks are in the shape of a square, etc.).

I've imagined the screen as a grid of which each cell either has a brick or doesn't, and place them using for loops. My trouble is dynamically loading the data. Right now I have the grid data in terms of arrays. I've half attempted to upload 1 json file, but didn't succeed.

I'm not sure how to go about this problem. Do I make individual json files for each level? Can json files even have jagged arrays? How would I extract the data as an array? Is there a way of doing this with playerprefs?

Any help would be appreciated

```
public class BrickGrid : MonoBehaviour {
    string filename = "data.json";
    string jsonString;
    string path;

    public Transform brickPrefab;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Bricks {
        public string[] rows;
    }

    void Start() {
        LoadGridData();
        InitGrid();
    }

    void LoadGridData() {
        path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + filename;

        if (File.Exists(path)) {
            jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);
            BrickPattern rows = JsonUtility.FromJson<BrickPattern>(jsonString);
        }
    }

    void InitGrid() {
        int[] row1 = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
        int[] row2 = { 1, 1, 0, 1 };
        int[] row3 = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };

        int[][] rows = new int[][] {row1, row2, row3};

        Vector2 brickPosition = new Vector3(-2.25f, 4f, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++) {
            int[] individualRow = rows[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < individualRow.Length; j++){
                if (individualRow[j] == 1){
                    // instantiate
                    Instantiate(brickPrefab, brickPosition, Quaternion.identity);

                }
                else if (individualRow[j] == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                // inrease x position
                brickPosition.x = brickPosition.x + 1.5f;
            }

            // increase y position and reset x position
            brickPosition.x = -2.25f;
            brickPosition.y = brickPosition.y - 1.5f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just having a txt-file where each line is like "1100","1100"?

Comment: What happened when "but didn't succeed"?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create a prefab for every level, just design them under one `GameObject` and create a Prefab from that `GameObject`. Now when you change the level, instantiate the correct prefab.
I think that would be the easiest way.

You could also try many other ways.
Hardcode the locations for each bricks on each levels and use those information when you "dynamically" load a new level.
Store the position values somewhere else (file, database, etc.).

Hope this helps.